# API name with .php calling from WSO2 API manager ISSUE

Tags: php, api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 API manager 1.7. and need to publish an API written in php. It's endpoint url is coming with .php aslo. But when I publish that API and call it via APIM, it never give any response. I noticed following exception in the carbon log.
If I try with directly with the url, API gives correct response.
This is a get request and I'm passing url parameters.

Can you please help me how to solve this issue.

```
API URL : <host>/api/testApi.php
```

Error Log

```
TID: [0]  [AM]  TID: [0] [AM] [2016-09-06 15:43:22,016] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} -  Error while building Passthrough stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:129)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:107)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:70)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.axiata.dialog.verifier.MifeInternalAPIResponseHandler.handleResponse(MifeInternalAPIResponseHandler.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:83)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:51)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming when the content body is built. Make sure you are setting the correct content-type header and make sure the relevant Message Builder is enabled in axis2.xml

Comment: This API type is GET. So when we send a api call via GET request no need to send header parameter unlike in PUT or POST request with json body. And also axis2.xml is working fine, because all other my APIs are working really well. Only the difference here is just calling .php file not a properly defined web service

Comment: can you share the API response? also you can use tcpmon to see what do you send to the backend and the backend response.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's better If you can enable wire logs to see all the messages that are passing through, 
**by enabling wire logs you can confirm when you sending a api call via GET request it is working or not** 
you can enable the wire level logs. It will log all http messages. to do this

Please uncomment following two properties in "log4j.properties" file which can be found at APIM HOME/repository/conf directory

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

Comment: I resolved this issue by publishing another API on ESB and calling from ESB to this backend. Then its working fine.

Comment: I know above method is not the best solution. because it may apply another dependency to the platform and add some more delay time even with milliseconds.